# Mediaplayer error Android for lollipop+ error (1,-38)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-5.0-lollipop, forward-compatibility

In my app, i do video streaming and it work on 5.0- devices. For above 5.0, it doesnot. it gives (1,-38). 1 means this is unknown error. So is there anybody that has any ideas ?

```
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity, Uri.parse(token.url), null);
```

This is the line that i set the datasource.

```
try {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity, Uri.parse(token.url), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                setState(PLAYER_STATE.STOPPED);
                return;
            }
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Thanks

Comment: -38 from the MediaPlayer is an invalid state transition. Plz post your code.

Comment: i added a snippet code